# How to load data from yml files onto a HUGO template

Tags: parsing, documentation, yaml, hugo

How can I load data from  yml files onto a HUGO template? I am having trouble understanding the [documentation](http://gohugo.io/extras/datafiles/), what would be the steps?

I am using the hyde template.

Answer (score 4):

Given a Yaml-file named `mydata.yml`:

- Put this file into the folder `/data` inside your Hugo project. If it doesn't exist, create it. The exact name is important.
- From the template you can then access the Yaml file as a data structure with `$.Site.Data.mydata`. Nested elements can be accessed by so called dot chaining: `$.Site.Data.mydata.author.name`